# MYSQL: insert on duplicate update - get current column value

Tags: mysql

I want to access current value of column in "on duplicate update".

For example, I have a table with structure:

```
unique_param value
test        test_value
```

unique param is a UNIQUE index.

And query is

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`unique_param`, `value`) values ('test', 'test_value1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = concat(VALUES(value), ",", value)
```

But my query does not work, seems I can't access to current column, so value after query is "test_value1,"

the result I expect is:

```
unique_param value
test        test_value1,test_value
```

**UPGRADE:**
Based on Gordon answer, my query is fine and if needed, somebody can use it. I just had an error in table definition.

Comment: what is VALUES doing there @ end

Comment: VALUES(value) get "value" that I try to insert, i.e. test_value1 . So, I hope that final result will be: "value" that I try to insert + "," + value from existing column, i.e. "test_value1"  + "," + "test_value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works on [SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9669/1)

You just need to insert a duplicate key . . . the name of the column does not count as a duplicate.

By the way, storing things in a comma-delimited list is almost always a bad idea.  Use a separate junction table instead.

Comment: thank you, yes, my code works :) My mistake was in table definition on local server, not in query. By the way, it is ok to store comma-delimeted list in my example, I hope, because I don't use it for filtering and don't want to build index on this "value" field